# Google Maps API V2. Пикселей на 1 метр?

Tags: google-maps-api-2

Привет.
Делаю свой TileProvider, понадобилось отрисовать на тайле окружности некоторого радиуса, заданного в метрах.
Вопрос: как правильно перевести радиус в метрах в пиксели с учетом zoom'a?

Answer (score 2):

Перевод из метров в пиксели:

```
private static final float EARTH_RADIUS = 6371000; 
private static final int TILE_DIM = 512;

private int meters2pixels(float meters, double lat, int zoomLevel)
        {
            long map_width = TILE_DIM * (int)Math.pow(2, zoomLevel);
            double metersPerPixel = 2 * Math.PI * EARTH_RADIUS * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat)) / (double)map_width;
            return  (int)(meters / metersPerPixel);
        }
```